# Status of __STDC_IEC_559__ with modern C compilers

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, clang, ieee-754

C99 added a macro `__STDC_IEC_559__` which can be used to test if a compiler and standard library conform to the ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559 (or IEEE 754) standard.

According to the answers for this question
[how-to-check-that-ieee-754-single-precision-32-bit-floating-point-representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404213/how-to-check-that-ieee-754-single-precision-32-bit-floating-point-representati) most C compilers don't set the preprocessor macro `__STDC_IEC_559__`.

[According to GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) it does not define `__STDC_IEC_559__`.

I tested this with GCC 4.9.2 and Clang 3.6.0 both using with `glibc` 2.21 using the following code.

```
//test.c 
//#include <features.h>    
int main(void) {
#if defined ( __STDC_IEC_559__ )
//#if defined ( __GCC_IEC_559__ )
    return 1;
#else
    return 0;
#endif
}
```

and then

```
echo $?
```

This shows that with this code `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined with GCC but not with Clang. I then did `gcc -E` and it showed that the file `stdc-predef.h` is included. This file defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`.

```
/* glibc's intent is to support the IEC 559 math functionality, real
   and complex.  If the GCC (4.9 and later) predefined macros
   specifying compiler intent are available, use them to determine
   whether the overall intent is to support these features; otherwise,
   presume an older compiler has intent to support these features and
   define these macros by default.  */

#ifdef __GCC_IEC_559
# if __GCC_IEC_559 > 0
#  define __STDC_IEC_559__              1
# endif
#else
# define __STDC_IEC_559__               1
#endif
```

This confirms that it's `glibc` that defines this macro and not GCC.

However, when I include `features.h` (or `stdio.h`) this file is included by Clang as well and that `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined.

So `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined by both GCC and Clang (with a `glibc` header file) which seems to disagree with the answer to the first question I linked to.

I then tested [`musl`](http://www.musl-libc.org/) (e.g. `musl-gcc -test.c`) which is a different standard library than `glibc`. This showed that `__STDC_IEC_559__` is not defined with `musl`.

As I understand it the standard C library does not define the basic  floating point algebra. For example the standard C library does not define the result of `1.0/-0.0`. This is defined by the compiler.

My questions are (ranked in order of importance to me):

1. Why is `__STDC_IEC_559__` defined by `glibc` and not by the compiler?
2. If I made my own standard library and I wanted to define `__STDC_IEC_559__` I would need to know that the compiler already conforms to IEEE 754 for operations not defined in my standard library (e.g `1.0/-0.0`). Is there documentations for this or a macro to test for this?
3. [Wikipedia states that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#IEEE.C2.A0754_floating_point_support) "users should be aware that this macro (`__STDC_IEC_559__`) is sometimes defined while it shouldn't be". Is this statement still accurate?

Comment: MinGW doesn't define the macro. I have no idea why.

Comment: @this, that's interesting. Do you mean MinGW-w64 or MinGW? They are different. I also tried 32-bit mode with gcc -m32 test.C and `__STDC_IEC_559__` was still defined.

Comment: @Zboson Sorry, I meant w64.

Comment: @this, okay, w64 is more intersting in my opinion anyway. What happens when you include `<features.h>`. What about with `gcc -E`? Is `stdc-predef.h` ever included?

Comment: @Zboson features isn't available for c. -E has no effect, why would it? I don't think so.

Answer (score 4):

1. I believe `__STDC_IEC_559__` relies on some library features and can't be defined solely by the compiler.  See [this post](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2009-04/msg00005.html) for some information.  This is not uncommon for C -- the compiler and the C library must sometimes cooperate in order to implement the entire standard.
2. What you're asking depends on the compiler.  I think you would have to have special knowledge of the compiler in order to decide this.  In the specific case of GCC, it defines a macro to tell you.  Search [this node of the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) for `__GCC_IEC_559`.
3. Well... I don't know the answer to this one :-).  The original post seems to indicate that, yes, GCC might define `__GCC_IEC_559` if it *intends* to implement IEEE 754, even if it does not actually do so.

Comment: `__GCC_IEC_559` is not defined by test.c in my question by GCC 4.9.2 but `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined.I should probably have mentioned that in my question. It would make a lot more sense if `__GCC_IEC_559` was defined.

Comment: In regards to my third question I think it my be referring to [this](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2005-03/msg00196.html). But that's from 2005...a long time ago.